# Trouble adding double the divs i already have

Tags: jquery, html

Okay so I am creating a game for fun. The game involves a 5 second timer and divs shapped like boxes. the first round you start off with 1 div the purpose is for you to click on that div before the timer runs out. if you pass you go to the next level which adds double the boxes so level 2 you have 2 boxes level 3 4 boxes and so on. I am having trouble creating always double the length of the div. I dont have much code because nothing ive tried has worked. here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JZdkQ/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery Project: An exploding game</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body, html {
width: 960;
height: 500%;
}
div.box {
position: relative;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: orange;
}
div.exploding {
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: red;
}
</style>


</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You used length() when you just need length. It is a property, not a function.

Comment: @mitch what do you mean? would you be able to show me on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript...

`setTimeout(function(){$("body").append("<div class='box'></div>").length() *2;}, 5000);`

is saying...

> After 5 seconds get `<body/>` and append a `<div class='box'/>` to it, get the number of divs we just appended (i.e. 1) and multiply that number by 2 then discard the result.

Use this...

`setInterval(function(){$(".box").clone().appendTo("body");}, 5000);`

it says...

> Every 5 seconds, get all the elements of class box, make a copy of them, and append the copy to body.

http://jsfiddle.net/JZdkQ/2/

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval` rather than `setTimeout`. `setInterval` is used for events that happen repeatedly based on the time you set, while `setTimeout` happens once.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JZdkQ/1/)

Comment: Thanks but its only adding 1 div at a time i need to add double the divs that are already on the page

Answer (score 0):

Awesome! If I where you I would put the doubling length staff in a function, that I will call recursively.

Comment: My bad i am new to jQuery just building stuff so i can learn you know. how exacly would I do that?